# Testing if conditional was called in my AngularJS unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have set up my unit tests in AngularJS with a Karma test runner and a Jasmine test framework. My code coverage report nicely shows me which lines and conditionals have been covered in my test. It is with this coverage report that I realised an `if` conditional in my code (see below) is not being tested. Do I need to create a mock for the `angular.forEach()` call? And if so, how exactly to do this? With ngMock?

To make my question a bit more clear, I would like to provide you with an example using an `if` conditional in an `angular.forEach()` call.

Say for example I have the following service:

```
angular.module('myApp').service('myService', function () {
  function myFunction(myFunctionParameters) {

    // ... Some irrelevant code...

    var x = [];
    angular.forEach(xObjs, function(o) {
      if (some condition) {  // <--- Code coverage says this is not tested!!
        // do something...
      }
    });

    // ... Some more irrelevant code

    return // Something //
  }

  return {
    myFunction: myFunction
  };
});
```

A test for "myService" could be something like this:

```
describe("myService", function() {
  // Some variables  
  // Declare the mocking variable
  // Invoke the module
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));   
  beforeEach(function(){
    // Define the mock variable
    mockVariable = <define mock variable here>
    module(function($provide) {
      $provide.value('serviceToMockName', mockVariable);
    });

    // Inject the services
    inject(function(_myService_) {
      myService = _myService_;
    });

    // Spy on the mock
    // Call myFunction function in myService
    result = myService.myFunction(functionParameters);
  });

  // Write some tests for the myFunction call in myService
  describe("myFunction", function() {
   it("should test the if condition...", function() {
     // How to make sure I did the condition check in the if statement!!
   });
  });
});
```

**CODE COVERAGE**

Highlighted in green is lines 21, 22 and 24. The only line highlighted in red is 23, which is the `if` condition. So the coverage says that I am entering the `if` (since line 24 is highlighted in green) but the `if` condition itself is not covered?

```
21  11          var x = [];
22  11          angular.forEach(xObjs, function(o) {
23  55            if (o.values.length) {
24  55              x.push(o.values[o.values.length-1]);
25                }
26              });
```

Answer (score 0):

not possible dirrectly like that. but you can set a variable in your service after and in your if condition.
like that you will be able to recover in your test to check if it have been called.

```
expect(yourService.getVariable()).toEqual(theValueThatYouExpect);
```

To go forward you can imagine to increment a varaible in your function to check how many time the if have been called.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I evaluated your answer but I don't think this is the solution to my problem. I edited my question to include the code coverage example, clearly explaining how all lines are "covered" except the actual if itself? Any ideas? Also, correct me if I am wrong in thinking this, but it doesn't feel right to add code to my service, that will 'only' be to count a variable that I will use in my unit tests?

Comment: yes truly code coverage is proper way to identify this. I use Karma-coverage to do this on my project. It's interesting because it give you a report line by line if the coverage is done or not :  https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-coverage

Comment: Same here. I use karma-coverage to do this, and use gulp to run my tests. Still though, I am unable to figure out how to make sure my "if" condition is covered in the test?